# Make it so that turtle can't cross turtle-drawn lines

Tags: python, python-2.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game, similar to adventure for the Atari 2600, using turtle in Python 2.7.15.  Can I make it so that turtle can't cross turtle-drawn lines?

I need my turtle to do certain things when it detects a certain color, like have it not be able to cross green or open a door when it hits blue. Bonus points if you can help me figure out how to have a collectible (key) follow the turtle after turtle touches it.  Here's my code:

```py
from turtle import *
import turtle as t

color = raw_input("Enter an avatar color in the form of a hex code (Black won't show because the background is black): ")
c = Turtle()
loop = 0

def bdr():
    c.color(color)
    c.up()
    c.goto(0,-185)
    c.seth(90)
    t.ht()
    t.bgcolor("#000000")
    t.color("#00ff00")
    t.speed(0)
    t.up()
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(200)
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(200)
    t.rt(180)
    t.down()
    for box in range (4):
        t.fd(400)
        t.lt(90)
    t.up()
    t.fd(200)

def k1():
    c.seth(90)
    c.fd(5)

def k2():
    c.seth(180)
    c.fd(5)

def k3():
    c.seth(0)
    c.fd(5)

def k4():
    c.seth(270)
    c.fd(5)

bdr()

onkey(k1, "Up")
onkey(k2, "Left")
onkey(k3, "Right")
onkey(k4, "Down")

listen()
mainloop()
```

I haven't attempted any sort of color detection, as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you *not* base collision detection on color.  It's possible if you drop down to turtle's tkinter underpinnings, but since your turtle is moving inside a box, it's much simpler to test coordinates:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

SIZE = 400
DISTANCE = 5
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def draw_border():

    border = Turtle(visible=False)
    border.color("green")
    border.speed('fastest')

    border.penup()
    border.goto(-SIZE/2, -SIZE/2)
    border.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        border.forward(SIZE)
        border.lt(90)

def k1():
    player.setheading(90)

    if player.ycor() + DISTANCE < SIZE/2:
        player.forward(DISTANCE)

def k2():
    player.setheading(180)

    if player.xcor() - DISTANCE > -SIZE/2:
        player.forward(DISTANCE)

def k3():
    player.setheading(0)

    if player.xcor() + DISTANCE < SIZE/2:
        player.forward(DISTANCE)

def k4():
    player.setheading(270)

    if player.ycor() - DISTANCE > -SIZE/2:
        player.forward(DISTANCE)

color = raw_input("Enter avatar color as a hex code (black won't show): ")

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

player = Turtle(visible=False)
player.speed('fastest')
player.color(color)
player.up()
player.sety(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2)
player.setheading(90)
player.showturtle()

draw_border()

screen.onkey(k1, "Up")
screen.onkey(k2, "Left")
screen.onkey(k3, "Right")
screen.onkey(k4, "Down")

screen.listen()
mainloop()
```

As far as doors and keys, if you make them turtles as well, you can simply use turtle's `.distance()` method to do your collision detection.